# Class "MAHARSHIABI\Settings\App\Providers\SettingServiceProvider" not found in laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

https://github.com/maharshi-abi/laravel-settings this package is use in my laravel application. this project is run on localhost. but it gives error on cpanel Class "MAHARSHIABI\Settings\App\Providers\SettingServiceProvider" not found in laravel 9. Need help to solve issue.

laravel project gives following error  Class "MAHARSHIABI\Settings\App\Providers\SettingServiceProvider" not found in laravel 9.

Comment: If it works fine locally, have you ran composer on the server its not working on?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Yes I am copying same project on cpanel.